# XSD - allow element type as integer OR empty

Tags: xsd, element

I need to be able to set a simple element type as an integer but allow it to also be empty.  This example sends an error if its empty and a blank field is not an integer.  How can I get round this?

```
<xsd:element name="weight" type="xsd:integer"/>
```

Comment: Did you try skipping the element from your original XML and marking minOccurance =0 in XSD?

Comment: See https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2003May/0063.html

Answer (score 33):

What you have to do is assign restrictions on the same element plus make a union on them such as the following example:

```
<xs:element name="job_code">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
          <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:integer' />
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

By using this restriction, you tell the xml validation to allow any integer value and allowing the element if it is empty.

Comment: In this case, if the attribute is not "required", what default value will be the parser if it is an attribute: empty string or 0 ?

Comment: Interesting reading here : http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/09/06/solving-unmarshalling-problems-with-jaxbcxf/

Answer (score 10):

We can achieve this by making a SimpleType

```
<xs:simpleType name="NullOrInteger">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="\d*|\s{0}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Add **NullOrInteger** as the type where you want restriction for an integer or null value.

for example:

```
<xs:element name="null_or_int" type="NullOrInteger" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the "nillable" attribute as true:

```
<xsd:element name="weight" type="xsd:integer" nillable="true"/>
```

See the [XML Schema Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils).

Comment: Ive tried that but get this error: Element 'minimumQuantity': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:integer'

Comment: @leanne - that error does not make sense given the snippet of XSD that you posted.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="products">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="product" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1" type="productType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
 <xsd:complexType name="productType">
    <xsd:sequence>
>    
     <xsd:element name="weight" type="xsd:integer" nillable="true" />
   
    </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType> 
</xsd:schema>

Comment: The XML Schema is above as requested.  The Error message is the same whether or not Nillable is included, it has no effect.  The XML element "weight" is empty, but if I add an integer, then obviously this works, but I need to allow the XML node to have a value or be empty.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @leanne - that schema that you posted includes spurious text, including a semi-colon and a closing bracket. After seeing those, I didn't bother to look closely at the content. And, to repeat *pangea*, you haven't produced your XML; I suspect, given the error message, that it's failing for reasons other than an empty element. Please post a complete, self-contained example program, **in your post** if you want further help.

Comment: The approach using nillable requires that empty elements contain an xsi:nil attribute, e.g., `<weight xsi:nil="true"></weight>`. An empty element without that attribute still wouldn't pass verification.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <product>
        <weight xsi:nil="true"/>
    </product>
</products>
```

Try the above, should work; most likely you forgot to add the xsi:nil attribute. Also, make sure that the weight element has no character as children (a white space would still not be acceptable). If you do have to pass some characters instead of an integer, than you have to define a union type to allow for both.

Answer (score 1):

I came up to this answer by searching how to get an attribute to be a nullable Integer, using xsd schema, and based on which JAXB classes are generated. I found no answer here, so after I discovered the answer, I decided to share it. The following xsd portion will generate a not nullable type of int (int):

```
<xsd:attribute name="length" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
```

In Java code this will result:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "length", required = true)
protected int length;
```

If we drop the use required, we will get:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "length")
protected Integer length;
```

Hope this helps someone. And even if this answer might not be related to the actual question, I find it useful to be here for those who will get here by doing the same search I did!

Comment: Your answer covers an attribute, this question is about an element. Just saying.