# Cannot parse empty Decimals/Integers in XML with Schema

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, schema, decimal

I am getting confused here... Trying to parse a simple XML file, with a Schema, and I am getting errors.

Here is a simple code:

```
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(retXML);
            txtRead = new StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
            tmpDS = new DataSet();
            tmpDS.ReadXmlSchema(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/schemas/pnrView.xml"));
            tmpDS.ReadXml(txtRead);
```

Then I am getting this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) at System.Data.Common.DecimalStorage.ConvertXmlToObject(String s) at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadColumn(DataColumn column, Object[] foundColumns) at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested) at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested) at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadData(XmlReader reader) at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving) at DotNetNuke.StSystem.Bookings.GetPnrView(NameValueCollection formData)

Here is the xml:

```
<PNRView>
<PNR>
    <PricePPPN_UserCurrency/>
    <PricePP_UserCurrency/>
    <PriceTotal_UserCurrency/>
    <PricePPPN_LocalCurrency/>
    <PricePP_LocalCurrency/>
    <LocalCurrency>EUR</LocalCurrency>
    <PrCur>EUR</PrCur>
    <PrTotal>0.0000</PrTotal>
    <PrTotalEUR>0.0000</PrTotalEUR>
    <ServiceNotes/>
</PNR>
</PNRView>
```

Here is the schema:

```
                <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
            <xs:schema id="PNRView" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <xs:element name="PNRView" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="PNR">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="PricePPPN_UserCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="PricePP_UserCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="PriceTotal_UserCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="PricePPPN_LocalCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="PricePP_LocalCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="LocalCurrency" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="PrCur" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="PrTotal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="PrTotalEUR" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" default="0" nillable="true" />
                                        <xs:element name="ServiceNotes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
```

I tried every combination of minoccurs/nillable/default, the xml passes validation in FreeFormater.com, how ever C# has a different opinion.

Comment: Can your CultureInfo influence the number format ?

Comment: It could, however I do not believe this is the case.
PrTotal is parsed correclty. Only empty fields have problem.

Comment: I have nothing to try out on my hands, but check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19927519/956660

Answer (score 0):

Attributes `nillable="true"` and `minOccurs="0"` only works when no element is send. To allow empty as a value, you must use union to allow integer values and have a case if element is empty.

```
<xs:element name="PrTotal">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
          <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:integer'>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Now I am getting another error:
DataSet doesn't support 'union' or 'list' as simpleType.

Comment: The only related [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b31e6052-6c4d-4175-83c1-0088354c863f/dataset-doesnt-support-union-or-list-as-simpletype#507724f5-8ab8-4331-86e0-d453cdc4c8a3) that I found suggest using [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/s74fh1h1(v=vs.110).aspx)