# Validate on an integer or empty

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xsd element:

```
<xs:element name="Runtime" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
```

How would I change it so it accepts a positive integer or empty?

```
<Runtime>1</Runtime>
<Runtime></Runtime> <-- This will currently fail -->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD - allow element type as integer OR empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109910/xsd-allow-element-type-as-integer-or-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be:

```
<xs:element name="Runtime">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{1,}|"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```